# esp32 crashes when waiting for XQueueRecieve to watch for uart interrupt

Tags: c, debugging, esp32, freertos, interrupt-handling

(EDIT): Solved, I was trying to access the uart ringbuffer at the same time in two different tasks and never released the output. Changing that now removed the crash.

So when this runs I get to the point where it waits for any input from the uart in order to terminate the running process; However, when I provide that input the system aborts and reboots...anything standing out as glaringly obvious?

*I know it looks like a lot of code, but I posted everything relevant just for context. The core spots to look are: **app_main(void), run_time, and uart_Stop_ISR.***

Here is main:

```
void app_main(void)
{
setbuf(stdout, NULL);//ensures that printf statements are not buffered waiting for carriage returns.

configureUart();
NED_Var *bubba_Data=malloc(sizeof(NED_Var));
initStruct(bubba_Data);//sets initial values of the structure

printStructData(bubba_Data);//prints the struct values

isr_semaphore = xSemaphoreCreateBinary();


vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));


xTaskCreate(startMenu,"start menu", 2048, &bubba_Data,2,NULL);
vTaskDelay(10);

xTaskCreate(uart_Stop_ISR, "uart isr", 1024, &bubba_Data, 4, NULL);
vTaskDelay(10);

for(;;)
{
  vTaskDelay(10);//needed to give idle task time to reset the WDT
}

free(bubba_Data);
}
```

Here is are the tasks/functions/structs used:
This is the struct that holds pretty much everything of value.

```
typedef struct NED_Var
{
  uint32_t date_time;
  char *DUT;
  uint32_t SN;
  double idleVoltage;
  uint32_t freq;
  bool atxClampEn;
  uint8_t stop;

} NED_Var;
```

I rewrote an uart input using the esp32's read/write bytes functions since scanf was a "no-go".

```
/*************************************************************
 * Function: uint8_t* bubba_RX
 * 
 * Description: allows the user to utilize the uart in a more simplified fashion
 * 
 * Arguments: nothing
 * 
 * Returns: a uint8_t* item
 * 
 * Notes: The esp32 requires use of non standard uart serial read/write interfaces
 *        Therefore this function makes using them simpler, and provides a more standard feel
 * 
 ***/
uint8_t* bubba_RX()
{
    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(char));
    uint8_t *data2= (uint8_t *) malloc(BUF_SIZE);

      for(int i=0; data[0] != 13; i++)
      {
        int len = uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM_0, data, sizeof(char), portMAX_DELAY);
        uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_0, (const char *) data, len);
        data2[i]=data[0];
        data2[i+1]=0;
      }
      
      // printf("Data2 is: %s\n", (char*)data2);//for debugging

      return data2;
      
}
```

simple function to configure the uart of the device, pretty sure its mostly redundant at this point because default setup would work.

```
/*************************************************************
 * Function: void configureUart
 * 
 * Description: Configures the Uart device for serial communication
 * 
 * Arguments: none.
 * 
 * Returns: nothing
 * 
 * Notes: Must be called in order to use any sort of serial communication.
 * 
 ***/
void configureUart()
{
    uart_config_t uart_config = {//this allows the user to configure the uart however they might need. default is typically fine
      .baud_rate = 115200,
      .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
      .parity    = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
      .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
      .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
      .source_clk = UART_SCLK_APB,
  };
  
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_driver_install(UART_NUM_0, BUF_SIZE * 2, BUF_SIZE*2, 20, &uart0_queue, 0));
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_param_config(UART_NUM_0, &uart_config));
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_set_pin(UART_NUM_0, ECHO_TEST_TXD, ECHO_TEST_RXD, ECHO_TEST_RTS, ECHO_TEST_CTS));

  
}
```

initializes my struct to use reasonable values

```
/*************************************************************
 * Function: void initStruct
 * 
 * Description: Initializes the structure to "sane" values
 * 
 * Arguments: Ned_Var * struct
 * 
 * Returns: nothing
 * 
 * Notes: This comes up upon POR every time
 * 
 ***/
void initStruct(NED_Var *param)
{
  param->date_time=0; 
  param->freq=10000; 
  param->SN=0;
  param->DUT=(char*)malloc(512); 
  param->DUT="XAmple6666";
  param->idleVoltage=2.1; 
  param->atxClampEn=false;
  param->stop=1;
  }
```

allows the user to input data to the struct, I know I need to add input filters

```
/*************************************************************
 * Function: void getStructData
 * 
 * Description: allows the user to enter operational points
 * 
 * Arguments: Ned_Var * struct
 * 
 * Returns: nothing
 * 
 * Notes: This comes up upon POR to allow initial setup of the test enviroment
 * 
 ***/
void getStructData(NED_Var *param) 
{
  printf("\nEnter the date: ");
  param->date_time=atoi((char*)bubba_RX());
  printf("\nEnter data for serial number: ");
  param->SN=atoi((char*)bubba_RX());
  printf("\nEnter data for DUT: ");
  param->DUT=(char*)bubba_RX();
  printf("\nEnter data for Idle Voltage: ");
  param->idleVoltage=atof((char*)bubba_RX());
  printf("\nEnter data for frequency: ");
  param->freq=atof((char*)bubba_RX());
  printf("\nEnter data for ATX_En 1 or 0: "); 
  param->atxClampEn=atoi((char*)bubba_RX());
}
```

prints out current struct values

```
/*************************************************************
 * Function: printStructData
 * 
 * Description: Prints the passed struct data
 * 
 * Arguments: Ned_Var * struct
 * 
 * Returns: nothing
 * 
 * Notes:
 * 
 ***/
void printStructData(NED_Var *param)
{
  printf("\n\nThe struct data is: ");
  printf("\n Date: %08d",param->date_time);
  printf("\n S/N: %d",param->SN); 
  printf("\n DUT: %s",param->DUT); 
  printf("\n Idle Voltage: %.2f",param->idleVoltage);
  printf("\n ATX Clamp Enable: %s",(param->atxClampEn ? "true":"false"));
  printf("\n Frequency: %d\n",param->freq);
}
```

allows the user to update a single item in the struct

```
/*************************************************************
 * Function: void updateParam
 * 
 * Description: Allows the user to update a single parameter of Ned Var Struct
 * 
 * Arguments: Ned_Var * struct
 * 
 * Returns: nothing
 * 
 * Notes:
 * 
 ***/
 
void updateParam(NED_Var *param)
{
  printf("\n---------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("Select the parameter you would like to update:\n");
  printf("1) Date, currently: %d\n", param->date_time);
  printf("2) S/N, currently: %d\n", param->SN);
  printf("3) DUT, currently: %s\n", param->DUT);
  printf("4) Idle Voltage, currently: %.2f\n", param->idleVoltage);
  printf("5) ATX_Clamp_En, currently: %s\n", param->atxClampEn ? "true":"false");
  printf("6) Frequency, currently: %d\n", param->freq);
  uint8_t result=atoi((char*)bubba_RX());

  switch (result)
  {
    case 1:
      printf("\n Enter the new Date: ");
      param->date_time=atoi((char*)bubba_RX());
      break;
    case 2:
      printf("\n Enter the new S/N: ");
      param->SN=atoi((char*)bubba_RX());
      break;
    case 3:
      printf("\n Enter the new DUT: ");
      param->DUT=(char*)bubba_RX();
      break;
    case 4:
      printf("\n Enter the new Idle Voltage: ");
      param->idleVoltage=atof((char*)bubba_RX());
      break;
    case 5:
      printf("\n ATX Clamp En enter 1 or 0(True/False): ");
      param->atxClampEn=atoi((char*)bubba_RX());
      break;
    case 6:
      printf("\n Enter the new frequency: ");
      param->freq=atoi((char*)bubba_RX());
      break;

    default:
    printf("That was not a valid option, please start again\n");
      //break;
  } 
}
```

prints current struct values

```
/*************************************************************
 * Function: printStructData
 * 
 * Description: Outputs a menu that lets users adjust settings or begin testing
 * 
 * Arguments: a Void param that must actually be a Ned_Var * struct
 * 
 * Returns: nothing
 * 
 * Notes: FreeRtos requires its functions to be void function(void *param), otherwise we would directly pass the Ned_Var * struct
 * 
 ***/
void startMenu(void *param)
{
  NED_Var *tmp_pnt=param;
  // SemaphoreHandle_t beginTest = xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
  // if(beginTest != NULL)
  //   printf("\nSemaphore created successfully\n");
  // vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(500));

  for(;;)
  {
    uart_flush_input(UART_NUM_0);
    fflush(stdout);
    vTaskDelay(10);
    printf("\nWould you like to begin testing?(y/n)\n");
    uint8_t *response = bubba_RX();
    
    switch ((uint8_t) *response)
    {
      case 89: //user entered "Y"
      case 121://user entered "y"
        printf("Are you sure you would like to begin?(y/n)\n");
        response=bubba_RX();
        tmp_pnt->stop=1;
        if(strcmp((char*)response,"y"))
        {
          // xSemaphoreGive(beginTask); //tells the interface to release control to the lower priority task that runs the test 
          
          runTime(param);       
        } 
        break;

      case 78: //user entered "N"
      case 110://user entered "n"
        printf("\nWould you like to update one or more parameters?(one/more)\n");
                response=bubba_RX();
        if(strcmp((char*)response,"one"))
        {
          updateParam(param);
      
        }
        else
        getStructData(param);
        
        break;

      default:
        printf("\n %s is not a valid entry\n",(char*)response);
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

just a function that gets kicked off by the startmenu function to output runtime information. This function provides the semaphore that unlocks the task that waits for uart input to end this test.

```
/*************************************************************
 * Function: void runTime
 * 
 * Description: takes a semaphor when the test is ready to begin and outputs the runtime data specified in the header file
 * 
 * Arguments: a Void param that must actually be a Ned_Var * struct
 * 
 * Returns: nothing
 * 
 * Notes: this function can only be started when called by the higher priority task
 * 
 ***/
void runTime(void *param)
{
  NED_Var* temp_pnt=param;
  temp_pnt->stop=1;
  xSemaphoreGive(isr_semaphore);
  printf("\r Pulse Voltage: %f.2|Test Time: %s| Hit Any Key to Exit", 12.21, "tbd");
  while ((temp_pnt->stop)!=0)   
  {
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(500)); 
  }     
    printf("\n Outside of the while loop now\n"); 
}
```

the function that waits for uart input to end the test

```
/*************************************************************
 * Function: void IRAM_ATTR uart_Stop_ISR
 * 
 * Description: waits for a semaphore to get started then blocks at a queue waiting for input
 * 
 * Arguments: a Void param that must actually be a Ned_Var * struct
 * 
 * Returns: nothing
 * 
 * Notes: n/a
 * 
 ***/
void IRAM_ATTR uart_Stop_ISR(void *param)
{
  NED_Var* temp_pnt=param;
  uart_event_t event;
   for(;;)
  {
    xSemaphoreTake(isr_semaphore, portMAX_DELAY);
    xQueueReset(uart0_queue); 
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(3000));
    if(xQueueReceive(uart0_queue, &event, portMAX_DELAY))
    {
      if(event.type == UART_DATA)
      {
        temp_pnt->stop=0;
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Everyone in this community understands that you are going through a lot of trouble. But that is way too much code – and less likely anybody would put efforts to help you. Thus, what you need to do is to make the question a little shorter. In other words, [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I mean the core of the problem is really just the last 2 functions. The rest of the code is jus there for context if someone wants to look at it.

Comment: What's in the crash dump?

Comment: you will run out of memory in no time if you use bubba_RX the way you do. use ```uint8_t data[1];``` instead of ```uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(char));```; you are not freeing memory returned by bubba_RX(); - better use static buffer instead of mallocs in this function i.e. ```static uint8_t data2[BUF_SIZE];``` and use ```z = strdup(bubba_RX())``` when you need to preserve data returned by this function. And where your ```uart0_queue = xQueueCreate(NUMBER_MESSAGES, sizeof(uart_event_t));``` ?

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion @MaximSagaydachny! I glazed over that not giving it much thought about resource management.